# Setting a lot of PivotItem.visible properties painfully slow - how do I speed it up?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot

I have a PivotTable with 1378 distinct values for a specific field (CO), based on 18000 lines of data or so.

Filtering only 7 out of these values in a manual way takes **less than 1s.**
Recording this, then running the macro takes **105s.**
Optimizing the code speeds this up to **58s**.

This is still far from optimal. Are there any other ways to speed this up? I'm running this on an i5 3rd gen, so that's not it either...

```
Sub test()
    Dim i, t As Integer
    Dim pvi As PivotItem
    Dim startTime As Double

    startTime = Timer
    Sheets("Analyse BE WBS").Select
    Application.StatusBar = "CLEARING WBS"

    'FASTER...
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").ManualUpdate = True

    'clear all items: this is the time consuming part
    For Each pvi In ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("CO").PivotItems
        If pvi <> "(blank)" Then
            pvi.Visible = False
        End If
    Next

    'selecting the wanted items
    Application.StatusBar = "selecting specific CO WBS"
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("CO")
        .PivotItems("ICA").Visible = True
        .PivotItems("IGR").Visible = True
        .PivotItems("ILI").Visible = True
        .PivotItems("IPO").Visible = True
        .PivotItems("ITR").Visible = True
        .PivotItems("P020").Visible = True
        .PivotItems("P021").Visible = True
        .PivotItems("P022").Visible = True
        .AutoSort xlAscending, "CO"
    End With

    'restore it
    Application.StatusBar = "refresh"
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").ManualUpdate = False
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotCache.Refresh
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

    'timer results in 58s
    MsgBox Format(Timer - startTime, "00.00") & " seconds"

End Sub
```

Comment: As far as I know, you have to live with what yov've got.

Comment: A few ideas: 1) is `...StatusBar` function necessary? Seems like that might add some overhead; 2) Turn off "ScreenUpdating" sooner; 3) Don't use `.Select` (search SE for reasons)

Comment: It's about a half second on my ADM A4 3.4GHz. That's setting 1,499 out of 1,500 pivot fields to hidden. I even added a bunch of other fields to see if the bulk would slow it down. It didn't. If you have a ton of, say, column fields, maybe getting rid of them, doing your thing, then adding them back.

Comment: I have a data source sheet of about 18.000 rows by 35 columns. In this particular Pivot, about 15 columns are used as filters (~8 page filters, 4 row filters, 3 column filters). That doesn't seem extravagant to me. I'll try running this on some different machines to see if it's an installation issue. Did you also use Excel 2010?